# Logstash can't read files it should have access too

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ubuntu-12.10, logstash

I've added user `logstash` into group `adm` using the command `$ usermod -a -G adm logstash`.

One of the files that the logstash agent is trying to read is `/var/log/nginx/foo-access.log`, which has the following permissions:

```
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm 0 Jul 25 07:52 /var/log/nginx/foo-access.log
```

When I `sudo su logstash` I can read the file, BUT, when I `$ sudo service logstash_agent restart` (which the init script runs as the `logstash` user) it fills up the logstash logs with:

```
{:timestamp=>"2013-07-31T17:05:17.287000+0000", :message=>"failed to open /var/log/nginx/foo-access.log: Permission denied - /var/log/nginx/foo-access.log", :level=>:warn}
```

I can confirm the logstash user is in the adm group:

```
$ groups logstash
logstash : logstash adm
```

This file definitely has the right file access:

```
$ getfacl /var/log/nginx/foo-access.log
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/log/nginx/foo-access.log
# owner: www-data
# group: adm
user::rw-
group::r--
other::---
```

I've tried turning it off and on again.

Comment: Your file doesn't seem to have the correct group write permissions. Chmod to fix

Comment: I don't want to write to the file, like I said I want to read it.

Comment: I assume you also checked the parent directory permissions (`/var/log/nginx`)

Comment: getfacl /var/log/nginx/kapture-api3-access.log

Comment: I added the output of that command to the question. I'd ran it before with the results I expect, so didn't bother initially.

Comment: The error message has `kapture-api3-access.log` while your examples are `foo-access.log`. I'm guessing the "foo" file vs error log file-name difference is just an oversight and not literally what the file name is?

Comment: lol, yeah this is just me not bothering to obscure all names.

Comment: Another quick test, you said you got it to work by su the user. Can you try giving the user just read access to the file and seeing if it works.

I just don't feel that read access is all you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out to be related to this bug in upstart:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/812870

Because `adm` was a secondary group it was not being applied to the process, which is broken as f**k and is apparently fixed in a later version.

My solution was to add `setguid adm` to the init file.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working workaround:

```
sudo vi /etc/init.d/logstash
```

modify

```
    LS_GROUP=logstash
```

by

```
    LS_GROUP=adm
```

then

```
sudo /etc/init.d/logstash start
```

Comment: Also works by adding "LS_GROUP=adm" to /etc/defaults/logstash - the nice part about that is that it's easier to manage using puppet .